# How do I (can I) use attr() to get the z-index, a CSS property, for use with calc() in my style definition?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the position of a specific div element `id="test"` on the page relative to its z-index, using the CSS `calc()` and `attr()` methods, such that when the z-index changes, the position changes proportionally.

However, it seems that it evaluates the `attr(zIndex)` as a value of one in all cases, causing the desired element to stay in place despite the modified values of zIndex. Is there a correct way to access the CSS values from within the style definition itself, or do I have to do all of this in JavaScript?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>zLinkTestPage</title>
        <style>
            body { background-color: #000000; }
            div { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; display: block; }
            #test {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: calc( attr(zIndex) * 10px );/*This line is the one in question*/
                background-color: #ff0000;
                z-index: 0;
                width: 144px; height: 288px;
            }
            #ref {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #00ff00;
                z-index: 1;
                width: 288px; height: 144px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ref">Reference div</div>
        <div id="test" onmouseenter="moveZ(2);" onmouseleave="moveZ(-2);"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Test div</div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function moveZ(amount) {
            var box = document.getElementById("test");
            var curZ = box.style.zIndex;
            if(curZ == "") {
                //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
                curZ = 0; //because, for some reason, the initial value of any CSS property when accessed by JavaScript always seems to be null of some sort...
                //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
            }
            else {
                //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
                curZ = parseInt(curZ);
                //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
            }
            var newZ = curZ + amount;
            box.style.zIndex = newZ;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This is an exercise for myself and will only be used to make much cooler stuff later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that isn't possible just with CSS. You can, however, reference the HTML attributes on an element in the CSS property `content`, and reference HTML attributes in CSS selectors.

So using your code, you could actually create a `zIndex` (not CSS `z-index`) attribute attribute on the element (or I created a `data-zIndex`), then reference that in a `content` attribute

```
#test:after {
  content: attr(data-zIndex);
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can use a CSS selector to target the element based off of the value of that attribute like...

```
#test[data-zIndex="0"]:after {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#test[data-zIndex="2"]:after {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Here's a demo with those changes.

```js
function moveZ(amount) {
  var box = document.getElementById("test");
  var curZ = box.getAttribute('data-zIndex');
  if (curZ == "") {
    //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
    curZ = 0; //because, for some reason, the initial value of any CSS property when accessed by JavaScript always seems to be null of some sort...
    //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
  } else {
    //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
    curZ = parseInt(curZ);
    //console.log((typeof curZ) + " curZ=" + curZ);
  }
  var newZ = curZ + amount;
  box.setAttribute('data-zIndex',newZ);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc( attr(zIndex) * 10px);
  /*This line is the one in question*/
  background-color: #ff0000;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 144px;
  height: 288px;
}

#test:after {
  content: attr(data-zIndex);
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test[data-zIndex="0"]:after {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

#test[data-zIndex="2"]:after {
  background: yellow;
}

#ref {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 288px;
  height: 144px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ref">Reference div</div>
<div id="test" data-zIndex='0' onmouseenter="moveZ(2);" onmouseleave="moveZ(-2);"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Test div</div>
```

Comment: So CSS alone can't necessarily contain specific, scalable relationships between its variables. I guess I'll just need to continue my JavaScript implementations of all these just-beyond-the-edge cases. Thank you for your answer.